# Error while passing data with segue - objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

i am trying to pass some data while doing a segue, but am getting the error

> Chat System[2501:974283] -[UIViewController setVisitid:]: unrecognized
>   selector sent to instance 0x17e22a10  Chat System[2501:974283]
>
> ---
>
> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIViewController
>   setVisitid:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17e22a10'

Here is my code

```
- (void) goToTransferChat {

        TransferChat *dvc2 = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"id_chat_transfer"];
        [dvc2 setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical];
        dvc2.visitid = self.visitorID;
        dvc2.visitame = self.visitorName;
        dvc2.visitStartTime = self.visitorStartTime;
        [self presentViewController:dvc2 animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

**TransferChat**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface TransferChat : UIViewController

@property(strong, nonatomic) NSString *visitid;
@property(strong, nonatomic) NSString *visitame;
@property(strong, nonatomic) NSString *visitStartTime;



- (void) getAllOperators:(NSString *) profileToken;
- (void)setupProfileidURL:(NSString *)profileId companyId:(NSString *) companyID;


@end
```

Comment: `dvc2.visitid = self.visitorID;` in that piece of code is `dvc2.visitid` String? And make sure you have `@Synthesize` the property in `TransferChat.m`

Comment: Are you sure the visitid you are passing is NSString.

Comment: Did you check the `[dvc2 class]`. Does it return `TransferChat`?

Comment: yes everything is a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set class to your storyboard controller like below:

[image]

Try to set Custom call here